# SAS refer to a single digit out of a whole number

Tags: sas

Do I have a way to refer a value in the following way => 
value=23032017 and I want to refer to the digit in the forth place of this number, i.e 2

Comment: Is it numeric or character field? You could convert to char and use substr() function to extract a character.

Comment: numeric. if so, is there a relevant function as for strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a number then use some simple arithmetic.

```
data _null_;
  value=23032017 ;
  do position=1 to 9;
    digit = mod(int(value/10**(position-1)),10);
    put position= digit= ;
  end;
run;

position=1 digit=7
position=2 digit=1
position=3 digit=0
position=4 digit=2
position=5 digit=3
position=6 digit=0
position=7 digit=3
position=8 digit=2
position=9 digit=0
```